# Views display labels with empty fields

Tags: views

I've created this view that displays content an author creates in a table. Trouble is, this view only appears once the author creates at least one piece of content, is there a way to show the labels by default? ie. even when there is no content in the fields?

I tried playing about with no result behaviour, but that just overrides the whole thing. I know there is a lot of info out there on how to hide fields if there is no result but i'm looking for the opposite.

Here's the table:
[image]

Here's the view:
[image]

Cheers,
Rumman

Answer (score 1):

Yes, under Advacned Options for the View there is a `No Results` option. You can set a `global text result` as an example and say "sorry no values found." Then under the `Table` format `Settings` there is a checkbox to `show No Results text in Table`. That will replace the empty row with your message -- while still showing the table headers.